# Lotus Notes is reporting: 'RRV bucket is corrupt.' when attempting to open an NSF database

Tags: corruption, lotus-notes, ibm-domino

I'm using the Lotus Notes Client version 8.5.2 on Windows. Its reporting error code 0x139e, 'RRV bucket is corrupt.'. I've tried opening it with and without the "fixup" flag but both fail with the same message.

There seems to be lots of suggestions floating around in the Domino forums but no definite answers. What's the best course of action (if any)?

Answer (score 2):

> RRV stands for Record Relocation Vector. It is a pointer that tells
>   Notes where to find a specific NoteID.

There seems to be no solid solution for this. It depends where and how the table is corrupted. Usually these errors call for a set of actions, and a bit of luck. If none of the actions solve the issue, the backup is the only way out.

Replacing the design with the template could help. (If there is no template, create one from a backup version of the database)
Design elements are notes also, so this might help.

Other options are:
- fixup
- compact
- compacting the workspace
- Replacing the desktop.ndk